# Using the Contains() and Add() methods on my list of string but it doesn't run

Tags: c#, static

In the code below I'm running the `RepeatedNames` method on a list called `listOfNames` with some of them being repeated. So the method is supposed to store the repeated ones in another list (`_repeatedNames`) and printing them out in the console.
But it doesn't run.

Just to mention: I'm new to C# and trying to learn in a practical way through coding, so there must be something obvious that I'm doing wrong.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        List<string> listOfNames = new List<string>() { "Sam", "Mark", "Nick", "Laura", "Mark", "Helen", "Nick" };
        RepeatedNames(listOfNames);
}


private List<string> _names = new List<string>();
private List<string> _repeatedNames = new List<string>();

static void RepeatedNames(List<string> NameCollection)
{
        foreach (var name in NameCollection)
        {
        if (!_names.Contains(name))
        {
                 _names.Add(name);
        }
        else
        {
                 _repeatedNames.Add(name);
                 Console.Write(name + "\t");
        }  
}
```

Comment: FYI `doesn't run` isn't really informative. Your Visual Studio instance should tell you what problem you are currently facing. Next time look into your error list - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/error-list-window?view=vs-2019

Comment: In your case the error list should look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/57Ym4.png - and with this information, the solution to your problem should be rather obvious. - If the error text alone doesn't help, you can click on the error code `CS0120`, which navigates you to the documentation of this error, with useful information and samples. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0120?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0120)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious mistake I made was, not using the word **static** in my lists' declaration.

Every time the `foreach` loops through, it's dealing with each item in the list, so in order to be able to use the `Contains()` and `Add()` methods on my lists (which are non-`static`), I should create an object instance of them. If not, I should mark my lists as `static` so that no instance of them is needed when invoking those two methods on them.

So the code in the question is missing the keyword `static`, and it'll look like as below:

```
private static List<string> _names = new List<string>();
private static List<string> _repeatedNames = new List<string>();
```